# Need help explaining how the elasticity was derived

Tags: calculus, economics

We had a lecture on calculating elasticity in microeconomics and I need help understanding how the answer was derived. I didn't quite get how we came up with the answer. My classmate said to just substitute, but what happened to *.03I - .4P + 2P*?

Demand function for *goodx*:

**Q<sub>x</sub><sup>D</sup> = 5 - 2P<sub>x</sub> + .03I - .4P + 2P**

Find the E<sub>x</sub><sup>D</sup> where P<sub>x</sub> = 2 and Q<sub>x</sub><sup>D</sup> = 1

```
ExD = 2QxD / 2Px = 2 * 2/1 = -4
```

Interpretation: Thus, / E<sub>x</sub><sup>D</sup> /=4, generally means that every 1% increase in the price of *goodx* will result to a 4% decrease in quantity demanded, *ceteris paribus*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An economics question? It might belong in a different exchange, but i find myself partial to this one... we have the demand function for *good x*: **Q<sub>x</sub><sup>D</sup> = 5 - 2P<sub>x</sub> + .03I - .4P + 2P** and we want to 
 find the own price elasticity of demand, E<sub>x</sub><sup>D</sup>, where P<sub>x</sub> = 2 and Q<sub>x</sub><sup>D</sup> = 1.

```
ExD = 2QxD / 2Px = 2 * 2/1 = -4
```

The"2" in the elasticity in formula (2$ Q_x^D$) is really the "$\partial$" sign ($\partial Q_x^D$), representing a partial derivative (partial slope) and the correct formula is:

$ E_x^D = \frac{\partial Q_x^D}{\partial P_x} \frac{ P_x}{Q_x^D} = -2 \frac{2}{1} = -4$

Your interpretation is correct. What happened to *.03I - .4P + 2P*? When taking a partial derivative, the remaining terms (other than $P_x$), are treated as constants. Now, since the derivative is measuring the rate of change (or slope), and since the constant terms do not change, their rate of change is zero and they ($I, P, $and $P$) drop out of the elasticity term. Does this reply help?

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain this. I was not sure if this was an economics or math question. I just assumed it was a math question since it is about the method on calculating the formula. But thank you again, at least now I am beginning to understand derivatives.

Comment: @xandra you are most welcome.

Comment: @calculus thank for the correction.